# Set Cookie Android

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, android-webview

I have just learned how to use a webview in Android. Now I'm trying to store a 'dummy cookie' for my html page that opens in webview. I observe somewhat strange behavior that sometimes I have `Cookies.db` in my /data/data/package/app_webview and sometimes the cookie is not set and it doesn't exist.

What is app_webview folder and what does it exactly store? Right now I see a *Cache* folder inside it which has several files and their names suggests me they're encrypted or least to be bothered by the developer. So, I ignored them. Other than that sometimes I see *Cookies.db* and *Web Data.db* inside the app_webview folder.

My code to set the cookie is:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/cookieDemo.html");
```

The content of cookieDemo.html is (in case it's relevant):

```
<html>
   <head>  
      </script>  
   </head>
   <body>
      <form name="loginform">
         <input type="text" name="emppassNTL" />
         <button name="button" onclick="btnLogin.performClick(this.value);" style="height:30px;width:100px">Set Cookie</button>    
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

My intention is to set a cookie, every-time the button in html page is clicked. The code executed on button click is:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick(String str1) {
            Toast.makeText(mWebView.getContext(), "Set Cookie button click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Need to add cookie to webview here.
            CookieManager manager = CookieManager.getInstance();

            manager.setAcceptCookie(true);

            manager.setCookie(URL, "testCookie");
            CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
            cookieSyncManager.sync();
        }
    }, "btnLogin");
```

Though the *sync* method in CookieSyncManager is deprecated, I've tried to do a forceful sync. But still sometimes *Cookies.db* is visible and sometimes not. It might be a pretty basic mistake that I'm doing, but pardon me for that as I'm really new to this stuff.

UPDATE : I read up more regarding CookieSyncManager and found that cookies exist in RAM to speeden up the process. That sounds one possible reason of *Cookies.db* not being visible. Flushing to persistent storage is only done if I kill the app, and reload the page. This might be proper behavior but still I'd expect *sync()* to write to storage immediately.